# Computer restarted then ran disk check. Is my computer crashing?

Tags: crash

My computer shut down without warning. It restarted and started loading updates then said it had a scheduled disk cleanup. Now its sitting on `CHDSK is verifying usn Jounal`. This process doesn't end. Is my computer crashing?

Comment: What version of windows you are using? Do you know your system file? Is it FAT32, NTFS or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you asked it to do a check disk (CHKDSK), it will on the next reboot.  It might be running due to something crashing or it might be running because it was asked to.  You should be able to check the Event Viewer in the System log and see if there are any diskio events which might indicate if you have a faulty drive.  if it does it on every reboot, then you should have someone take a look at the drive to see if it needs to be replaced.  Do a backup in the meantime as a precaution... it never hurts to do a backup..

Comment: +1 specially for advise to backup. Really do it even if this crash was really ok!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your hard disk drive, a full `chkdsk` could take a very long time.  Whenever Windows detect that your system did not shut down properly last time, it "schedules" a `chkdsk` to find and fix errors on your hard disk.  Therefore it may not be the problem of your hard disk drive but there could be other errors (e.g. software bug, RAM error and many other reasons; as suggested by @MikeAWood please check your system log).

Regular backup minimize your data loss in case of future system failure; try to shut down properly every time helps you from seeing the `chkdsk` screen on system start as well.